# Saving two models in one admin form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I've written a CMS and two of my relevant models are `talk` and `attachment`. A talk can have many attachments. My problem is that when the user creates a new talk, they have to create the attachments in a separate window in a separate form.

For my project it is a requirement that the user create new attachments at the same time they create a new talk. The user can include a maximum of 5 attachment objects. At the moment `talk` looks like

```
class talk(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    ...
    attachments = models.ManyToManyField('attachment')
```

and `attachment` looks like

```
class attachment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    link = models.URLField("Attachment URL")
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Classes in Python should always start with an uppercase letter

Comment: What @Brandon said, but more generally, http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You could use an `InlineModelAdmin` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)

Since `attachments` is a `ManyToMany` field, you could do something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class AttachmentThroughInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = talk.attachments.through

class talkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AttachmentThroughInline,
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you. It's frustrating to know what the problem is but not what to search for in the docs.

Comment: `inlines = [ AttachmentThroughInline, ]` gives me `undefined name AttachmentThroughInline`

Comment: `AttachmentThroughInline` had to come before `talkAdmin`